# Recently switched ISP, having trouble with AWS

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, amazon-route53

As the title says recently my office has switched ISP's and since switching we've been having some trouble with AWS.

I've done my best to cover troubleshooting to the best of my ability to resolve but to no avail

The issues I've been experiencing seem to be stemming from the domain names we use in route 53. to give an example, we typically will connect to our AWS hosted database with MySQL workbench, in the past with workbench we were able to use a hostname in the hostname field - such as database.company.com - that would resolve to the private ip of the ec2 instance, but since this switch the only path that will work for us is using the public ip of the ec2 instance, this also works for web UI's too.

When I follow some simple troubleshooting tips like nslookup the domain name will resolve to that same private ip for the ec2 instance which led me to believe that Route 53 in AWS was influencing where the domain name was resolving to.

When I go into Route 53 in AWS I did indeed see that those domain names were pointing to the private IPs, out of curiosity I changed the IP of a non-production server to point to the public ip of that ec2 instance however no change in the result of an nslookup even after letting the TTL expire, still pointing to the private IP

Currently in our Route 53 we have private.company.com and office.company.com, each being their own private hosted zone with each A record pointing to the private IP of the ec2 instances as the were before.

Ive done my best to look in every place i could think and i may be leaving information out and i apologize, i feel like im at a dead end and im hoping this could be something simple im overthinking.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remember that those "private" IP addresess are only usable within AWS, unless you made a VPN connection from your office to AWS.

Comment: We do have a vpn we use that runs through AWS, i recently had some trouble with that but was able to resolve it by creating a new vpn connection. Why would it have worked in the past with the "private" IP's but once we switched it stops?
Thank you for responding too